# ¿Añadir un Objeto a un ArrayList y ese Arraylist añadirlo a otro Arraylist?

Tags: java

estoy realizando una practica sobre un solitario, para ello tengo 3 clases, carta,Montón(un arraylist de cartas), Baraja(un Arraylist de montones), bueno y el Main.
Mi problema es que añado una carta al montón y se añade, pero a la hora de añadir otra carta a otro montón distinto , se añade en el mismo, el resumen es que acabo con las 52 cartas en el mismo montón, en vez de cada carta en un montón distinto.

Esto es una parte del main, esta en un bucle for , coge una carta la crea y la añade, asi hasta las 52 cartas:

```
//AÑADO LA CARTA
                Monton monton;
                monton = new Monton();
                carta = new Carta(m1, m2);
                monton.add(carta);
                baraja.add(monton);
```

Esta la clase monton:

```
public class Monton {
    private static ArrayList<Carta> monton = new ArrayList<Carta>();

    public void add(Carta carta1) {
        monton.add(carta1);
    }
```

y Esta la clase baraja:

```
public class Baraja {
    private static ArrayList<Monton> baraja = new ArrayList<Monton>();

    public void add(Monton monton1) {
        baraja.add(monton1);
    }
```

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que te está causando ese comportamiento es que estás definiendo los atributos como estáticos (`static`).

Cuando un atributo es estático, el mismo es común a todas las instancias de la clase.
Cada vez que hacés `new Monton()` se crea una nueva instancia, pero su atributo `monton`, el `ArrayList`, es el mismo para todas las instancias.

Esto significa que cuando haces `add()` para agregar una carta al montón, no importa en que objeto de `Monton`, en realidad lo estás agregando al único `ArrayList` monton definido como `static` en la clase.

Para ver la diferencia quita el modificador `static` de la definición del atributo `monton`.